# How to reorder by Drag Drop in Kendo UI TreeList?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

```
     var treeDataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, Name: "Main Menu", Icon: "", View: "", parentId: null },
        { id: 5, Name: "Sub Menu 1", Icon: "", View: "", parentId: 1 },
        { id: 6, Name: "Sub Menu 2", Icon: "", View: "", parentId: 1 },
        { id: 7, Name: "Sub Menu 3", Icon: "", View: "", parentId: 1 },
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            expanded: true
        }
    }
});

$scope.TreeViewOptions = {
    dataSource: treeDataSource,
    height: 540,
    editable: {
        move: true
    },
    sortable: true,
    columns: [
         { field: "Name" },
        { field: "Icon" },
        { field: "View" }
    ]
};
```

Every thing is working fine, but I am unable to get column ordering working. Essentially what I need is to be able to drag drop the rows to set their display order.eg **i want to drag before and drag after functionality in the treeList like in treeView.**  in this example i want to drag *Sub Menu 3* to the *Sub Menu1* position an Vice Versa

This feature exists in Kendo UI TreeView widget. Is this feature supported in the Kendo UI Tree List Widget? If not, then is there a workaround to get it working?

Comment: I didn't get what you want. Your last question says you want to know if TreeList is able to have DnD, but the rest of your question is about TreeView. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. there is a feature in Kendo TreeView that is you can reorder the record by drag and drop but in the treeList we don't have this functionality so you can't reorder just add them as child or parent

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown i have edit the question can you please take a look ?

Comment: Can you create a working DEMO of your code?

Comment: @QaiserMajeed There is no feature allow you to drag before and after functionality in treelist - like the treeview. Your question is same this in tererik forum:
https://www.telerik.com/forums/treelist-drag-and-drop-behave-like-treeview